# Helper not found and breaks the site

Tags: magento-1, helper

I came across a **magento 1** issue where a **helper** cannot be found and it breaks the website. It happened once I installed my custom extension. I have this helper which is defined in config.xml:

Mymodule_Extra_Helper_Data

The error i'm seeing is:

```
Array
(
    [type] => 1
    [message] => Class 'Mage_Connector_Helper_Data' not found
    [file] => /var/www/vhosts/mastrum.com/dev.mastrum.com/app/Mage.php
    [line] => 547
)
```

Instead of Mymodule_Extra_Helper_Data magento is looking for Mage_Connector_Helper_Data.

Why is that? Any help appreciated!

Comment: Please post your config.xml and some related code where you want to call your helper?

Comment: Possible you are using that helper some where so magento is searching for it. Search your code